# Entity relationship being set to null on update of form with removed form element

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have a page to record a survey entity that has a one to many relationship with a question entity, that is each survey can have many questions. Questions are composed of a question and answer property.

My goal is to have a form that only displays questions elements if they have not already had answers that have been submitted and persisted...

The form I want is nested the survey form contains 1..n question forms.

Say there are two question form elements on the page, name and age. If I submit the name and leave age blank name is persisted, and age remains blank. I then go back and submit age. Age is persisted, and name is still in the database but the foreign key survey_id is set to null on the question table, and the relationship is lost.

In oder to hide the answers I am removing them using form events on the PRE_SET_DATA event if the model contains data for the given element.

Does anyone have any suggestions for things to look for here?

I have changed the submit method from handle request to $form->submit (with the clearMissing flag set to false) but the survey_id is still being set to null.  The submission is being done from the survey controller, do I have to also explicitly tell the question subforms to not 'clearMissing'?

*Edit: The solution I am considering is to add back the 'deleted' form elements and data on the PRE_SUBMIT form event, I think that would ensure that Doctrine won't assume the missing data requires a delete. I am not sure how sane this is though and if there's a better way?

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/client/{surveyIdentifier}/{clientIdentifier}", name="client_survey_form", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function clientSurveyForm(Request $request, $surveyIdentifier, $clientIdentifier,
                                     QuestionRepository $questionRepository): Response
    {

        $survey = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Survey::class)
            ->findOneBy(['surveyIdentifier' => $surveyIdentifier]);


        $form = $this->createForm(ClientSurveyType::class, $survey, [
        ]);

        $form->submit($request->get($form->getName()), false);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('client_confirmation',
                [
                    'surveyIdentifier' => $surveyIdentifier,
                    'clientIdentifier' => $clientIdentifier
                ]
            );
        }
    }

Survey Entity:

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SurveyRepository")
 */
class Survey
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", mappedBy="survey", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $questions;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Staff", inversedBy="surveys", cascade="persist")
    */
    private $staff;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="surveys")
    */
    private $client;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Job", inversedBy="surveys")
    */
    private $job;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $type;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
    */
    private $surveyIdentifier;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $clientSurveyUrl;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
    */
    private $clientComments;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $clientImpedimentForSurvey;





    Question Entity:




    /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
    */
    class Question
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $answerType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $answerChoices;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="questions")
     */
    private $survey;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $completionDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionTransactionLog", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $questionTransactionLogs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $attachmentFilename;
```

Comment: Crude and fast: Instead of automagically flushing your changes, you could retrieve the survey from the db and manually update the answers based on what was submitted

Comment: @Dimitris - I struggled with this for a few days before I finally tried the 'crude and fast' suggestion. It works fine, although it kind of bugs me that there isn't a cleaner way to do this. Thank's for the suggestion I probably needed the hit of pragmatism.

Comment: @Dimitris if you post this as an answer I will mark it accepted.

Comment: Done posting the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, instead of trying to make the "automagic" work, you can go the fast and crude way of retrieving the survey from the DB and manually updating the answers based on what was submitted by the user.
I hope this helps. I will update my answer if I find something more useful